# Safari frequently gets hijacked when visiting digg.com

Tags: malware, browser-hijacking

About 6 months ago, every so often, when visiting digg.com, my browser (Safari) would get redirected to some malware site for updating Adobe Flash. This happened both on my iPhone (not jailbroken) and on my desktop iMac. Lately, it has been happening more and more frequently to the point where it happens almost all the time. Weirdly, it doesn't seem to happen in other browsers (as far as I can tell).

I suspect it is a malicious third-party advertiser on the digg website. But it's annoying nonetheless. I'm interested to see what's causing this behavior and how I might defeat it.

Comment: It could be a man-in-the-middle attack, e.g. check to ensure that your DNS server is what it should be. Additionally check your OS to ensure that nothing has set custom DNS servers. In my developer networking tools for Waterfox when I visit `https://www.digg.com/` it shows the IP/port as `104.20.9.174:443`. Additionally my second guess would be a third-party advertiser redirecting users. The site seems to load fine for me. Does this happen for *any other websites* or just Digg?

Comment: Have you reinstalled Safari?

Comment: There is no question here. What would you like to know? Keep in mind that we are not a malware removal site.